# What does the tsconfig option "lib" do?

Tags: typescript

I have an existing project that has this line in tsconfig.json:

```
lib:["2016", "DOM"]
```

What is the purpose of this?

The only info I could find is this:

> Specify library file to be included in the compilation. Requires
>   TypeScript version 2.0 or later.

What does that mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the TypeScript "lib" option really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986494/what-does-the-typescript-lib-option-really-do)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This is a new typescript 2 feature and so it still lacks documentation, but you can read about it in the [What's new in Typescript 2.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#including-built-in-type-declarations-with---lib):

> with --lib you can specify a list of built-in API declaration groups
>   that you can chose to include in your project. For instance, if you
>   expect your runtime to have support for Map, Set and Promise (e.g.
>   most evergreen browsers today), just include --lib
>   es2015.collection,es2015.promise. Similarly you can exclude
>   declarations you do not want to include in your project, e.g. DOM if
>   you are working on a node project using --lib es5,es6.

There's also a list of the `API groups` that are supported and a very short example in that link.

Comment: thanks, can you provide a simple example of _built-in API declaration groups_? Is it a library of polyfills?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, your question has an example, also in the link I provided they have an example: `"lib": ["es5", "es2015.promise"]`. Another one is to target `es5` but to use `es6` features: `"lib": ["es6", "dom"]`

Comment: I meant that when I specify "lib": ["es5"], does it simply mean that I can use `es5` types in `ts` complaining of compiler, or some kind of poly-fills will be provided by `tsc`?

Comment: The different libs can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib They are definition files which the compiler uses

Comment: I see, thanks, so this basically means, that if I specify `"lib": ["es5"]` and don't specify "dom", `tsc` will complain about usage of DOM specific methods, correct?

Comment: Beware that including "es2015.promise" or whatsoever doesn't include a polyfill into your compiled code. Instead you just notify the compiler that your code is using promises and it should be okay with that. If you need to add promises polyfills, consider either importing the polyfill in your code or using babel with corresponding machinery (babel-preset-env) as a post-step (or next loader in webpack)

Comment: These groups make a promise to the compiler, "please don't complain about these APIs, I promise the browser will support them." E.g. If you add `es6` and _don't include polyfills_, old browsers will choke.

Comment: @SteveClay your explanation is so easy, it's like I would be 5 years old and I would certainly understand it! Thanks!