# Should the typescript lib setting dom be included when developing an angular 4 component?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.2

In [this article on distributing an angular library](http://blog.mgechev.com/2017/01/21/distributing-an-angular-library-aot-ngc-types/) the author says that it's a good idea to not touch the dom directly because it makes the component unusable inside web workers.

Should we thus leave `dom` out of the typescript `lib` compiler option or are there certain use cases where we absolutely need it?  Here's an example with dom included:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "es2015",
  "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
},
```

The sample [`tsconfig.json` compiler options](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/typescript-configuration.html) includes `dom` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't compile without "dom". The reason is that the angular libraries export methods/classes that consume/return "dom" types. So when you go to compile against angular, your compilation fails because it cannot find the types.

Answer (score 0):

> typescript lib setting dom be included when developing an angular 4

Yes.

## Reason

Angular is designed for the DOM.