# What is the use case for the tsconfig "lib" option?

Tags: typescript

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303385/what-does-the-tsconfig-option-lib-do) and [this code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib), it's clear that using `lib` in the `tsconfig` will *not* polyfill any functionality you're using that isn't supported in your target environment.

If that's true, however, what is the use case supposed to be? If I had a polyfill that I'd pulled in, like bluebird, I would be using the DefinitelyTyped definition files. Is there a combination of `target` and `lib` that is intended to fix a common pattern in TS?

Comment: If you're targeting browsers that have a native Promise, you can use `lib` to provide the definitions without using a polyfill.

Comment: but if that's my runtime, I'm targeting `es6` not `es5`, and TS will automatically know `Promise` is a thing

Comment: Yeah, that was just an example... it's used for JavaScript engine/runtime features that don't necessarily have a pre-made definition file. And for things which one runtime might provide, but another doesn't. For example, there may be a browser that needs `es5` for some things, like not supporting arrow functions, but does include, say, generators. You could use a combination of `lib` entries to suit the needs of that runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/39303385/11107541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `lib` includes the DOM, but you might be running in a non-browser environment like `node`, so getting rid of that is useful.

You also might be running in a webworker context, which has a separate `lib` setting.

You also might be using a comprehensive polyfill library that you don't need specific types for.

It's also possible your host e.g. supports some ES6 APIs but don't support a certain ES6 syntax, so you can "mix and match" to target environment that don't support 100% of any particular spec level.