# What does the TypeScript "lib" option really do?

Tags: typescript, lib

I have still not been able to find good answer for this. The "target" option defines, what version of Javascript the result will run on. The "lib" option is less clearly described anywhere. Seems like it is a more granular way to describe the target environment, but then it seems strange it affects what you can write in the .ts source files. Thought TS what as superset of JS, so why does it affect whether, e.g., `Promise()` is available or not? This seems like it does not only define the target but also affect what functions you have available in Typescript. Can someone explain that clearly or direct to an answer (there is none at typescriptlang.org or in the books I have looked at, e.g., "Specify library files to be included in the compilation", which explains absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Typescript does not have any built-in types all types come from a set of base definitions (located in the `lib` folder in the typescript install directory). By default the `target` defines which `libs` are included. For example the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) state:

> Note: If --lib is not specified a default list of librares are injected. The default libraries injected are:
>
> ► For `--target ES5: DOM,ES5,ScriptHost`
>
> ► For `--target ES6: DOM,ES6,DOM.Iterable,ScriptHost`

The basic idea is that while target is deals with language features (more specifically which language features need to be down compiled, ex: for-of, or arrow functions), the `lib` option deals with what facilities the runtime environment has (ie. what built-in objects look like, what they are).

Ideally the default `libs` for a given `target` should be used. We may, however, have an environment which supports some of the runtime facilities but not the language features, or we may target runtime with a lower `es` version and poly-fill some of the runtime facilities, which can be in general done for some things (ex: Promises).

Comment: But the libs also influence what features are available on the Typescript side? (Like Promise()) Why doesn't TS just polygons that always? Is that to declare non-TS facilities available in target environment?

Comment: Well, `Promise ` is a type so what I said applies. Typescript tries to have a minimal presence in the generated code. You want polyfills you need to add those yourself

Comment: Thanks. Was not able to find it really explained anywhere on typescriptlang.org

Comment: +1 For the list of default values. It is a shame that specifying just one library, such as `es2021`, nullifies the inclusion of everything else. One error corrected, 480 new ones created. This list saved a lot of hassle.

Comment: Where can I find the default libraries for a target?

Comment: @GarfieldKlon: The [Typescript source code contains a folder with all type libraries](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/main/src/lib).For each ES version there is a file named esXXXX.full.d.ts in this folder which is used as default if no lib option is given (see [here for the detailed mapping](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/686cb1b63c82e5eee4cd9f8bbdbcf657a4815ff7/src/compiler/utilitiesPublic.ts#L295)). These files list all indiviual libraries which are included by default.

Answer (score 63):

Remember, TS **never** injects polyfills in your code. It's [not its goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals). Complementing the accepted anwer:

`target` tells TS which ES specification you want the final/transpiled code to support. If you configure it as `ES5`, TS will down compile the *syntactic* features to ES5, so any arrow functions `() => {}` in your code will be transformed to `function () {}`.

Whatever you choose for `target` affects the default value of `lib` which in turn tells TS what **type definitions** to include in your project. If you have `"target": "es5"`, the default value of `lib` will be `["dom", "es5", "ScriptHost"]`. It's assuming which *functional* features the browser will support at runtime. Adding things to `lib` it's just to make TS happy - you still need to import the polyfill yourself in the project.

So in short: configure `target` first, and if you need any extra polyfill in your project OR you **know** your browser(s) will support this little extra feature, `lib` is how to make TS happy about it.

Example:
You need to support IE11 but also you would like to use promises. IE11 supports ES5, but promises is an ES6 feature. You import a promises polyfill, but TS is still giving an error. Now you just need to tell TypeScript that your code will target ES5 and it's safe to use promises in the codebase:

```
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["dom", "es5", "ScriptHost", "es2015.promise"]
```

Comment: This is by far the clearest, most concise answer I've read on this topic. Thanks!