# es6 features not compiling in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm having some trouble compiling es6 code.

I have a .ts file:

```
let a: number[] = [1,34,5,5,34,3];

console.log(a.find(no => no == 5));
```

When I run `tsc --module es6 --target es2015 src/test.ts` it compiles fine, however `tsc --module es6 --target es5 src/test.ts` doesn't seem to work? I would like to target es5, but doing so gives me the error:

```
Property 'find' does not exist on type 'number[]'.
```

Can't TypeScript compile to es5, or will I need to run babel on top of the TypeScript compiler?

Comment: you can't compile this to es5. Because there is no `find` in es5, and typescript doesn't compile functions that doesn't exist in target, but the syntax.

Comment: @HikmatGurbanli yes you can you just need to specify the lib :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I didn't know the solution, but the problem. Thank you for enlightening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript can compile to es5, the only problem is that the `find` method is defined in the `es2015` standard, so typescript will assume it will not exist.

Typescript has two ways of controlling what standard you compile to `target` which tells the compiler how to compile the syntax and `lib` which tells the compiler what the runtime environment looks like (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043439/using-latest-javascript-features-in-typescript-such-as-es2018/51044240#51044240) for more detailed answer with examples)

To target `es5` but get the `find` method you need to also specify the lib:

```
tsc --module es6 --target es5 src/test.ts --lib es2015,dom,scripthost
```

Note that typescript will provide no polyfills, you either bring your own or hope `find` exists in the runtime.