# Typescript tells me property 'padStart' does not exist on type 'string'. Why?

Tags: typescript

When I type in the chrome dev tools:

```
"1".padStart(2,0)
```

I get

```
"01"
```

But when I write

```
"1".padStart(2,0)
```

in my typescript project

I get

```
Property 'padStart' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

Why does Typescript complain? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`padStart` is defined in the `ES2017` standard. You need to tell typescript to use the apropriate typings (the ones for `ES2017`). You can do this either by setting the target to `ES2017`, if your runtime supports all the language features required by `ES2017` (which is probably not the case at the time of writing).

Another option is to just set the `libs` option in order to get the typings for runtime objects in accordance with `ES2017` but still compile down to whatever language version you are targeting.(Note that the runtime itself needs to support `padStart`, typescript will not provide any poly-fills)

You can do this in `tsconfig` using the `lib` option:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
        "scripthost"
    ],
    // ...

}
```

You can read more about lib vs target in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043439/using-latest-javascript-features-in-typescript-such-as-es2018/51044240#51044240)

Comment: Will the runtime need to support padStart even if I add it to libs?

Comment: @user1283776 The libs just tell the compiler the method exists in the runtime. They add no code. You need to use a polyfill is the runtime does not support it, typescript does not provide polifills

Comment: I'm using ES2020 and it's still giving me this error...

Answer (score 11):

To make TypeScript aware of [String.prototype.padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart), you need to specify `es2017` in the list of libraries in your `tsconfig.json`. If you do that, then TypeScript will assume that all the ES2017 features can be used which might not be exactly what you want.

Platforms like Node.js don't always implement the complete feature set of a new ECMAScript language specification, so it's safer to only add the language features where you are confident that they exist. If you are not sure which features are supported by your targeted platform, you can look them up on pages likes [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2017) or [MDNs browser compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#Browser_compatibility).

The `padStart` function is part of the String prototype, so it is sufficient to just add `es2017.string` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6", "es2017.string"],
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: Great to use ``es2017.string`` instead of only ``es2017``!

Comment: This is a great insight into pulling out particular parts of the libraries!

Answer (score 10):

TypeScript assumes by default that your transpiled code will run in the worst possible environment (for now, I hope, really the worst), i.e. in browser supporting only ES5. `String.prototype.padStart` [is an experimental feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) supported only in ES2017, so TypeScript can't be sure that at runtime it will be here and ready.

If you know that this "worst case" won't appear (you aren't targeting old browsers, or are using polyfills), you can make one of the following changes to your `tsconfig.json`:

1. Change your transpilation target. This forces your consumers to have ES2017 (or newer) runtime, but requires no more effort from yourself. In this case, set `target: "es2017"`.
2. Change the list of libraries available. In this case, if you're not sure that your clients will be modern enough, you must provide them polyfills for the ES2017 elements you are using. In this case, add `"es2017"` to the array in `lib` parameter (if it was empty, then it will be `lib: ["es2017"]`).

Comment: Thank you, good explaination! Even after adding es2017 to the libs, typescript is complaining. Do I need to do anything more, like run some kind of npm command?

Comment: Do I read your post correctly that id I add es2017 to the libs and have es5 as target, padStart will work on old browsers as well?

Comment: No, the opposite is right. When you have `target: "es2017"`, your code might not run on older browsers at all (because of syntax errors). When you have `lib: ["es2017"]`, your code will run, but any features added in ES2017 must be explicitly polyfilled.