# How to resolve typerror: string.padStart is not a function

Tags: javascript, string, forms

I'd like to add leading zeros to a field value, so that if its not 4 digits, leading zeros will be added to make it 4 digits. I have taken the field value and made it into a string but its giving me this error.

```
var relay=this.getField("RELAY NUM").value;
var relayString=relay.toString();

var leadingZeros=relayString.padStart(4,'0');


TypeError: relayString.padStart is not a function
5:Console:Exec
```

Answer (score 1):

padStart is defined in the ES2017 standard. You need to tell typescript to use the apropriate typings (the ones for ES2017). You can do this either by setting the target to ES2017, if your runtime supports all the language features required by ES2017 (which is probably not the case at the time of writing).

Another option is to just set the libs option in order to get the typings for runtime objects in accordance with ES2017 but still compile down to whatever language version you are targeting.(Note that the runtime itself needs to support padStart, typescript will not provide any poly-fills)

You can do this in tsconfig using the lib option:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
        "scripthost"
    ],
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by tsconfig, can i do this in adobe? I am also using javascript btw

Comment: I mean it is just a symbolic config file includes to your compiler config. The error you got is related your ES version. If you set it to ES2017 error will disappear.

Comment: Okay, so do i just add that to the top of the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52293096/5957038

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same. in java script it worked as expected.
but when I moved to type script I got this error.

I did as written [here](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/54050227.html)

you could create your own pad function:

```
function pad(num:number, size:number): string {
   let s = num + ""; 
   while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s; 
   return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

padStart is string function not a number function. So using String Function to convert to string.

```
var relay=this.getField("RELAY NUM").value;
var relayString=String(relay);

var leadingZeros=relayString.padStart(4,'0');
```