# Why ES5 target does not transpile everything to ES5 compatible code?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-5

My TypeScript config contains:

```
"target": "es5",
"lib": [
  "es2020",
  "dom"
]
```

Still, there are some modern features like `Array.prototype.includes` and `Object.entries` that are not transpiled at all. Why is that?

Comment: The `target` only transpiles to compatible *syntax*, it doesn't add methods and other API stuff. You would need to polyfill those.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56278563/3001761