# Typescript compiler does not convert String.prototype.replaceAll (ES2021) to target ES2020

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm trying to compile my ts code with the target **ES2020** as my node version is **v14.17.3**, according to the following **tsconfig**:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2020",
      "lib": ["ESNext.String"],
      "module": "commonjs",
      "allowJs": true,
      "outDir": "./build",
      "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

As `String.prototype.replaceAll` is not supported in node v14.17.3 I'm getting error when running the code below, probably because the compiler is not replacing `replaceAll` with a valid expression in the target ES2020:

```
const text = "my text"
const newText = text.replaceAll(' ', '-')
console.log(newText)
```

```
TypeError: text.replaceAll is not a function
```

Shouldn't Typescript compiler convert **text.replaceAll(' ', '-')** to a valid expression in the target ES2020?

Comment: `text.replaceAll(' ', '-')` is a syntactically valid expression in ES2020 so there's nothing to convert it to.  If you're asking why TypeScript doesn't *polyfill* `String.prototype.replaceAll()`, it's because [they don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276280/why-is-es7-array-polyfill-needed-despite-the-tsconfig-target-is-set-to-es5).

Comment: The "lib" field (https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) means "assume these features are supported in the environment where the generated JavaScript will run".  It doesn't mean that polyfills will be provided.

Comment: @jcalz I think it's supported in ES2021, not ES2020.  At least I had to target ES2021 to avoid an error in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play.

Comment: I'm saying that `text.replaceAll(' ', '-')` is a *valid expression* in every version of JavaScript that I know of.  So is `foo.bar(123)` and `text.scoobydoobles(' ', '-')`.   For all of those, the TypeScript compiler will emit that code to JavaScript as-is.  There's nothing to "convert".  On the other hand, `foo.bar(...baz)` is an invalid expression in ES5 but valid above that, and such an expression might be converted to something else depending on compiler settings.