# How can I check the Chromium version used by the latest Electron release?

Tags: javascript, electron

So apparently [since 2018 Electron has used an outdated feature set of JavaScript via older Chromium / Node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374353/es6-syntax-import-electron-require) so we can't use `import` ES6 syntax. According to an answer linked, the solution is to use babel. However, if Electron ever gets with the times, Id like to remove that extra step from my project. Where / how can I see which version of Chromium / Node is supported by the latest release of Electron? Preferably by looking at the GitHub page or documentation rather than having to install / test.

Comment: JavaScript runtimes don't implement *versions*, but *features*. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61836170/906113

Comment: @str thanks for the correction. I think I updated my phrasing accordingly

Answer (score 1):

[Electron releases page](https://www.electronjs.org/releases/stable) has a note everytime Chromium version is updated.

For instance, 11.0.5 has updated Chromium to 87.0.4280.88.

Apart from that, if you want to know which Chromium version your application is using, you can enable DevTools and see release information there.

Comment: Oh cool. Good to know. I know I left it out of the question but I suppose they also always mention when the version of Node is updated?

Comment: Wait on that documentation, on page two release 11.0 it says its using Node V12... Shouldnt that support `import`?

Comment: It does. Where are you getting the error? Runtime or on the editor?

Comment: nvm I found a github issue where they explain they're not supporting `import` until they support node v14 https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21457