# How to define new URL when using typescript

Tags: typescript, tslint

Below is my code

```
const url: any = new URL((global as any).window.location);
```

However, typescript says can not find name URL.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

**Short version**: The `URL` type is declared in the "DOM" lib. Add that to the `"lib"` section of your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["dom"],
    }
}
```

*(if you already have other entries under `"lib"`, that's fine too - just add `"dom"` to the array)*

**Long version**:

The `"lib"` compiler option indicates which groups of built-in type definitions TypeScript should include. For example, you may include the `"es2015"` group to include type definitions for features added in ES2015.

The `"dom"` lib option refers to types that exist in browser environments but not Node environments. The `URL` class is an example of that, so it's declared in the `"dom"` types.

Note that TypeScript includes the `"dom"` types by default. I'm guessing you've overridden the list to something else, and aren't including them in yours.

For more info, see:

- [TS compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)
- [What does the tsconfig option “lib” do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303385/what-does-the-tsconfig-option-lib-do)