# Clarification on functionality of Typescript's target and lib settings

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2017

When tsconfig.json has the following

```
"target": "es5",
"lib": [ "es6", "dom", "es2017" ]
```

it doesn't seem to convert es2017 constructs to es5.  For instance, the following will fail on IE11:

```
var foo = [1, 2, 3].includes(1);
```

Is this by design or am I missing a setting in tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Clarification on functionality of Typescript's target and lib settings

The simplified way I think about it is that `target` says what **syntax** the output JavaScript will have, and `lib` says what **API members** your TypeScript source code can use. There is more detail in the answers to these two questions:

- [Typescript- What is target in tsconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415942/typescript-what-is-target-in-tsconfig)
- [What does the tsconfig option "lib" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303385/what-does-the-tsconfig-option-lib-do)

> ...it doesn't seem to convert es2017 constructs to es5... Is this by design or am I missing a setting in tsconfig.json?

You're right. This is by design. TypeScript transpiles to the `target` syntax; it does not polyfill the API members that are missing from the `target`. [Here is a quote](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6468#issuecomment-171400551) from a core member of the TypeScript team:

> I think you're confusing transpilation with auto-polyfilling. TypeScript doesn't automatically polyfill for you like Babel does, but does perform syntactic downleveling (e.g. for arrow functions). If you want to use ES6 runtime prototype methods, I'd simply include an appropriate ES6 polyfill and its accompanying definition file.

If your `lib` includes API members (such as `Array.prototype.include`) that aren't present in the `target` runtime, then you need to install polyfills that provide those API members.

Comment: That's the confusion to me.  Things like arrow functions are converted, but other features from the same spec are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can see list **Browser compatibility** for includes method here.

[image]

In this, it did not support IE.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: Understood.  My question was whether Typescript automatically converts .includes (or other ES2017 statements) into es5.