# Typescript Node JS - `Property does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'`

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have another NodeJS app built with typescript and global.d.ts file everything works fine but my new application is giving error while running with `ts-node-dev ts-main-file.ts`

In new application I have global.d.ts file in src folder but its not recognized.

global.d.ts file contents

```js
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface Global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    sequelize: any;
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json file contents

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",

  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "outDir": "out/build",
    "types": ["reflect-metadata"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "tests/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

I don't know why it is not working but if someone can point out the missing piece then that will be lot more helpful.

Environment Details:
Node JS 15
ts-node-dev ver. 1.1.1 (using ts-node ver. 9.1.1, typescript ver. 4.1.3)
Linux (Pop OS 20.10)

Code snippet of file where I see the error:

```js
async connectWithDB() {
    const databaseName = 'local_server';
    const userName = 'test';
    const password = 'Test123$';
    const host = 'localhost';
    const dialect = 'postgres';

    global.sequelize = new Sequelize(databaseName, userName, password, {
      host: host,
      dialect: dialect,
      pool: {
        max: 50,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000,
      },
      define: {
        charset: 'utf8',
      },
    });

    try {
      await global.sequelize.authenticate();
      console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);

      process.exit(1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your provided info isn't enough please provide the content of the related file or modules such as: `ts-main-file.ts` in your description by editing it. Maybe you used a undefined property of `this` or `type: GlobalThis` which isn't caught by VS-Code/IDE but you're still getting error while compiling. Remember global `this` of Browser & NodeJs are different

Comment: Edited answer with code snippet of ts-main-fie.ts

Comment: in above code snippet If I change from `global.sequelize` to `const sequelize = ....` then everything is working fine

Comment: Where is `global.d.ts`? Is it under `src`? It's not clear why you're using `include` at all though....

Comment: global.d.ts is directly placed under the src folder. Don't we need `include` to point to src directory for typescript to look into?

Comment: No you don't need that.

Comment: You should not pollute `global this` with sequelize or other APIs. Try to avoid this. It's not a good practice. Instead use a separate file for it & then import it to other files or simply return the `Sequelize` instance from the function

Comment: Yeah I already extracted it in separate file and now with the help of static I'm returning the same same instance but I'm still curious to know why adding something in global is not working

Answer (score 0):

Using `global this`or adding properties to it might cause issues later on. `connectWithDB` would also leave a side effect to the `global` chain of Nodejs. Also it'd create multiple instance of the same object. So just return the `Sequelize` instance if the `authentication` is successful else throw a Error & end the process

```js
async connectWithDB() {
    const databaseName = 'local_server';
    const userName = 'test';
    const password = 'Test123$';
    const host = 'localhost';
    const dialect = 'postgres';

    const sequelize = new Sequelize(databaseName, userName, password, {
      host: host,
      dialect: dialect,
      pool: {
        max: 50,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000,
      },
      define: {
        charset: 'utf8',
      },
    });

    try {
      await sequelize.authenticate();
      console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
      return sequelize; //return the instance if you wanna use it elsewhere..
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);

      process.exit(1);
    }
  }
```

**On your top file of project hierarchy..** If you're using express

```js
//main.ts / server.ts etc...
import express, {Request, Response} from 'express';
const app = express();
app.set(...);
.....
.....
export const dbConnect = connectWithDB();

app.get("/route", async (req:Request, res: Response)=>{
  dbConnection.then((db)=>{
    // do whatever
   }
  )
})
```

**Or add it to the express request object..**

```js
app.use((req:Request, _, done)=>{
  dbConnection.then((db)=>{
    req.db=dbConnection;
     done();
   }
});
```

Now it will be available to all routes as `req.db`

Comment: Alternate approach is perfectly fine but I still cant put anything in global scope. Rather than setting in request object I created static variable as mentioned in my previous comment and its working they way it should. But I'm still curious to know why setting something in global scope is not working.

Comment: I think this is because of `typescript`. Because you added `dom` & `dom.iterable` in `lib` property of `tsconfig.json`. If you aren't working in browser environment then don't use this libs as `Nodejs` doesn't support `DOM` manipulation thus `global` is not recognized by `ts-node`. Try removing those from the array & let me know what happen...

Comment: Read this thread you might get an idea about the `lib` property of `tsconfig.json`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303385/what-does-the-tsconfig-option-lib-do

Comment: I did remove both the dom & dom.iterable from config when I realized that I dont need them but even after that I cant use the global variable

Comment: Updated my post with the latest tsconfig.json

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.

```
declare global {
  var sequelize: any;

}
```

instead of

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface Global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    sequelize: any;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare global {
   function signin(): Promise<string[]>;
   sequelize: any
}
global.signin = () => {};
global.sequelize = anything;
```

this will work hopefully